# "Commands out of sync" error in Python with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

**CONTEXT.** Python 3.9.1, Flask-MySQLdb 0.2.0, Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.5.1. I don't use stored procedures.

**PROBLEM.** I have a datatables that lists all my users, and each row contains a link to delete the record. I delete a record without problem (I use Ajax). But if I try to delete a second record, I alternately get one of these SQLAlchemy errors:

1. `2014, "Commands out of sync`
2. `This session is in 'prepared' state; no further SQL can be emitted within this transaction`
3. `Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back`

**WHAT I'M DOING (very abbreviated).**

Controller

```
@blueprint.route('/delete/<id>', methods=['POST'])
def delete(id):
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        User.delete(id)
        data = {
            'status': True,
            'msg': 'Deleted user'
        }
        return jsonify(data)
```

Model

```
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
Session = sessionmaker(engine)
sessionDB = Session()
def delete(id):
    sessionDB.query(User).filter(User.id == id).delete()
    sessionDB.commit()
```

**HOW I TRIED TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM (without success).**
I have tried the following, based on recommendations made elsewhere on the internet. None of the solutions found on the internet have worked for me:

1. I have changed the engine line for this: `engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, poolclass=NullPool)`
2. I have changed the engine line for this: `engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, pool=QueuePool(reset_on_return=False))`
3. After the `sessionDB.commit()` I have put the following lines (trying to put them separately, sometimes all, sometimes only two, etc):

```
1. sessionDB.flush()
2. sessionDB.close()
3. engine.dispose()
```

I'm stuck with this. Any suggestion is welcome.

Greetings.

Comment: You have a single session shared by all calls to `User.delete`.  If blueprint or whatnot handles requests concurrently, you end up issuing commands over the same connection used by your session concurrently. You should either pass the session to use to the function from outside, or use a context aware session registry: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/contextual.html#unitofwork-contextual. Since you mention using Flask-SQLAlchemy, have a look at its way of providing just that: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/

Answer (score 0):

Ilja Everilä's comment worked for me, so I put the solution here on his behalf.

This was the way I configured my database session:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.getenv('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
Session = sessionmaker(engine)
sessionDB = Session()
```

My problem disappeared with this new configuration:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.getenv('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
sessionDB = scoped_session(session_factory)

def delete(id):
    sessionDB.query(User).filter(User.id == id).delete()
    sessionDB.commit()
    sessionDB.remove()
```

Thank you very much!